# Add ALL in Bound DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, binding

I currently developing a webpage using C#. I have a `DropdownList` data bound with the data from my sql database. After the dropdownlist bind with my database, the item inside the dropdownlist are userA, userB, and userC. If i select any of the item inside the dropdownlist, the data of the particular user will show in the gridview.

So, what I am trying to do now is I want to add an **ALL** into the dropdownlist. When I click on the **ALL**, the data of each user will be shown in the gridview. How can I achieve that? Any advice? Thanks.

P/S: I dont want to add any extra button in order to show all the user data. I want to make it in the dropdownlist.

This is my code:

**WebApp.aspx:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Username" 
        DataValueField="Username">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Username] FROM [Accounts]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is what i have edited for a new Webpage. I do not call the data binding function in code behind.

Thanks for any helps.

This is the answer i am looking for:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Username" 
        DataValueField="Username" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value ="all" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Username] FROM [Accounts]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks everyone who is trying to help me.

Comment: Post some code,What have you tried till now?

Comment: What exactly do you bind to the dropdownlist? is it a DataTable? List of Objects? and How do you do that?

Comment: on selecting **ALL** in dropdownlist add your all item values as comma seperated to a hidden values and split them pass them your method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this:

Use this code after you bind the `DropdownList` with SQL data

```
ddlUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "all"));
ddlUsers.SelectedValue = "all";
```

Once this is done, you can make your select all user query based on this condition:

```
if(ddlUsers.SelectedValue == "all")
{
   // your SQL query to select all users goes here.
}
```

In HTML Markup you can add this like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Username" 
        DataValueField="Username">

<asp:ListItem Text="All" Value ="all" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can remove `Selected="True"` if you don't want this to be selected by default.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it is not what i want. Because i put it in page_load and it is not functioning. I think it is because the page will be loaded before the data binding. So after added the "ALL" then only data binding so the "ALL" will not appear. Or do you know how to add the "ALL" after data binding?

Comment: You can add it after you call  DropDownlIst.DataBind() function. I modified the code. Also make sure you place this code inside the condition `if(!Page.IsPostBack) { //this code }`

Comment: But my dropdownlist data binding is by using the arrow at the right edge of the dropdownlist. I do not have DropDownlIst.DataBind() function in my code behind. How can i call the code above after DropDownlIst.DataBind() function???

Comment: Please paste your Dropdown list HTML markup by editing your question.

Comment: Edited the answer. Kindly check.

Comment: The code cannot show the "ALL". But I try to add AppendDataBoundItems="True" then it works like what i want. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do few things to achieve this.

1)ddlUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "all")); add this line where ever you are binding the drop-down list.

2) use `SelectedIndexChanged` event of drop down like...

```
protected void ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
if(ddlUsers.SelectedValue == "all")
{
  //Call your SQL query from here and bind the result set with your grid.
  //if you need the id's of all the items in the drop down then write a loop and form a      //string with , separated valued and pass it along.
}

}
```

Comment: My dropdownlist data binding is by using the arrow at the right edge of the dropdownlist. I do not modify any code in code behind for data binding. So where should i add ddlUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "all")); ???

Comment: Can you bind your drop-down without the data source that you are using by clicking on small arrow button. I mean by writing query. if you can't can you use java-script to add only this item.

Comment: I have found the answer. And i post is after the question i asked. Thanks for your help.